# AccessDeniedException exception in java

Tags: java, file, exception

I have the following code where I need to catch `AccessDeniedException` exception

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException;

class MyFileClass {
  public void write()
    throws IOException
  {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("sample.txt");

    out.printf("%8.2f\n", 3.4);

    out.close();

  }
}

public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception
  {
    try {
      MyFileClass mf = new MyFileClass();
      mf.write();
    } catch (AccessDeniedException e) {
      print("Access denided");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      print("File not found");
    }
  }
}
```

In case *sample.txt* is read only, I get output as "**file not found**" rather "**Access denided**". I would like to understand what is the reason for this? Also, is the above structure for catching `AccessDeniedException` correct?

Comment: do not print, use e.printStackTrace() to get a detailed error message in the console

Comment: Print complete exception stack trace and paste it

Comment: Does the program find the file when it's not set to read only?

Comment: This is what helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28673369/1317559

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`AccessDeniedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/AccessDeniedException.html) is only thrown by the new file API; the old file API (which you use with this `PrintWriter` constructor) only knows how to throw `FileNotFoundException` even if the real filesystem-level problem is not "the file does not exist".

You have to use the new API to open an output stream to the destination file; *then* you can have meaningful exceptions:

```
// _will_ throw AccessDeniedException on access problems
final OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(filename));
final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out);
```

More generally, the new file API defines [`FileSystemException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystemException.html) (inheriting `IOException`), which all new, meaningful exceptions defined by the new API inherit.

This means among other things that you can clearly separate, in catch clauses, what is caused by filesystem-level errors and "real" I/O errors, which you can't do with the old API:

```
try {
    // some new file API operation
} catch (FileSystemException e) {
    // deal with fs error
} catch (IOException e) {
    // deal with I/O error
}
```

Comment: And OP is using `import java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException;` Is that necessary?

Comment: I can't quite make sense of your question... Yes it is, you need to import the exception and this is the package it is defined in...

Answer (score 1):

There is **NO** such `AccessDeniedException`  in `PrintWriter`.

`SecurityException` is the exception thrown by `PrintWriter`

> If a security manager is present and checkWrite(file.getPath()) denies
>   write access to the file

Comment: Sorry but unfortunately, that is wrong; the old file API is broken and _will_ throw `FileNotFoundException` if you don't have any access...

Comment: @fge  Please provide some docs. I don't know that. It will be helpful to me also.

Comment: Eh, unfortunately that has never been documented properly. Except for the fact that `AccessDeniedException` did _not_ exist in Java 6, and for compatibility reasons they couldn't change the exceptions thrown

Comment: @fge It's not that simple. You are both half right. A SecurityException is thrown if you're running under a security manager and your .policy file doesn't allow access to the file. A FileNotFoundException is thrown if the *operating system* doesn't allow access to the file.

Comment: @AJ - Accepting your answer, now I understand that PrintWriter doesn't throw AccessDeniedException. However, FileNotFoundException will be caught when client is trying to write in a file which exists on the specified path but has read only access.

Comment: @EJP yes, which is why I say the old file API is terminally broken: `FileNotFoundException` is useless

Comment: @fge I'm not interested in your views on the old File API. I am only interested in correcting your implication that this answer is wrong. It's incomplete, but not wrong.