# Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException when creating a file

Tags: java

I met the AccessDeniedException when creating a file under the C:\, anyone know how to fix it? BTW, I am already the administrator and I am using Windows 7.

```
Path path = Paths.get("C://afile");
Files.createFile(path);
```

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670576/getting-java-nio-file-accessdeniedexception-when-trying-to-write-to-a-folder)

Comment: To debug try `Path path = Paths.get("C://blah/afile");` Sometimes windows is strict about root folder