# java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException In Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, access-denied

I am trying to download file from spring boot resource folder. is its giving error as

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: src\main\resources\generatedFiles
```

**Download file location.**

[image]

**Downloading Code**

```
FileSystemResource fileResource = new FileSystemResource("src/main/resources/generatedFiles/");
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
headers.setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.attachment().filename("convertedCollection.feature").build());
headers.setContentLength(((FileSystemResource)fileResource).contentLength());
return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(fileResource);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException" when trying to write to a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670576/getting-java-nio-file-accessdeniedexception-when-trying-to-write-to-a-folder)

Comment: Your `fileResource` is an entire directory -- I think you're intending to read a single file.